# Capturar a URL através do código Admob

Tags: delphi, url, admob

Quero gravar a `url` do componente `BannerAd` após efetuar o Load, percebo que o componente passa a `url` ao navegador padrão do dispositivo. O código é o seguinte:

```
    unit Unit1;

    interface

    uses
    System.SysUtils, System.Types, System.UITypes, System.Classes,System.Variants,
    FMX.Types, FMX.Controls, 
    FMX.Forms, FMX.Graphics, FMX.Dialogs, FMX.StdCtrls,
    FMX.Controls.Presentation, FMX.Edit, FMX.Advertising;

    type
    TForm1 = class(TForm)
    BannerAd1: TBannerAd;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    private
    { Private declarations }


     public
    { Public declarations }
     end;

     var
     Form1: TForm1;

     implementation

     {$R *.fmx}

     procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
     begin
       BannerAd1.AdUnitID := 'Código fornecido pelo Admob';
       BannerAd1.LoadAd;
     end;

     end.
```

Alguém tem alguma ideia de como posso fazer?

Comment: Deve postar o código para facilitar o entendimento e a resposta.

Comment: ok, ja editei o post

Answer (score -1):

```
BannerAd1.AdUnitID := 'Aqui vem o id que é dado, com esse id carrega a propaganda';
BannerAd1.LoadAd;
BannerAd1.visible:= true;
```